# AWS - CloudFormation - MalformedPolicyDocument - SHARR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

So, this is a strange one. I'm actually using a pre-canned AWS solution that is failing to provision. I am following this document:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/automated-security-response-on-aws/deployment.html

The issue I am having is deploying the Template in STEP 2. Specifically, it calls out the below section:

```
Resources:
  OrchestratorMemberRoleMemberAccountRoleBE9AD9D5:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                Fn::Join:
                  - ""
                  - - "arn:"
                    - Ref: AWS::Partition
                    - ":iam::"
                    - Ref: SecHubAdminAccount
                    - :role/SO0111-SHARR-Orchestrator-Admin
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                Fn::FindInMap:
                  - ServiceprincipalMap
                  - Ref: AWS::Region
                  - ssm
        Version: "2012-10-17"
```

I have not edited this from what is provided, but the error that I get is as follows:

**"Invalid principal in policy: "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID:role/SO0111-SHARR-Orchestrator-Admin" (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: REQUEST-ID; Proxy: null)"**

I downloaded the template and have been attempting to re-format the problem section, but I'm having no luck.

Anyone able to help on this?

Answer (score 1):

> Invalid principal in policy

Often indicates that such a principle **does not exist**. To create IAM role, a principle must already exist beforehand.